# QSqlTablelModel cannot find SQL view, but QSqlQuery can

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I want to use `QSqlTableModel` since it seems easier to use. It does however not find my tables.

```
qDebug() << "connecting";
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName(dbHostName);
db.setPort(dbPort);
db.setUserName(dbUserName);
db.setPassword(dbPassword);

// Connect to database sys to get some info to test (basic communication)
db.setDatabaseName("sys");

// Check if opened and if so get some data
if(db.open()){
    qDebug() << "DB succesfully opened";
} else {
    qDebug() << "DB failed to open";
    return;
}

QSqlTableModel* runsSimulationViewModel = new QSqlTableModel(); 
runsSimulationViewModel->setTable("results.runs_simulation_view");

qDebug() << runsSimulationViewModel->lastError();
```

**//ERROR: QSqlError("", "Unable to find table results.runs_simulation_view", "")**

```
QSqlQuery anotherQuery;
anotherQuery.prepare("SELECT * FROM results.runs_simulation_view");

if(!anotherQuery.exec()) {
    qDebug() << anotherQuery.lastError();
} else {
    anotherQuery.next();
    qDebug() << anotherQuery.value("simulation_id").toInt();
```

**//Prints "3", which is the first value for this field in the table**

```
}
```

QSqlQuery works, but QSqlTableView cannot find this (SQL) view (and also no tables).

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you call `runsSimulationViewModel->setQuery(anotherQuery);` ?

Comment: I am having the EXACT same issue, so any help would be appreciated.